# Read journal exactly once

Tags: scala, akka, event-sourcing, akka-persistence

I'm using akka-persistence's PersistenceQuery to load initial state to my actor that manages stuff. I want it to replay exactly once on startup but it keeps sending those to log.

```
14:11:28.405 [rooms-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] DEBUG a.p.q.j.l.LiveEventsByPersistenceIdPublisher - request replay for persistenceId [rooms] from [4] to [9223372036854775807] limit [100]
14:11:28.407 [rooms-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-17] DEBUG a.p.q.j.l.LiveEventsByPersistenceIdPublisher - replay completed for persistenceId [rooms], currSeqNo [4]
14:11:31.376 [rooms-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-17] DEBUG a.p.q.j.l.LiveEventsByPersistenceIdPublisher - request replay for persistenceId [rooms] from [4] to [9223372036854775807] limit [100]
14:11:31.377 [rooms-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-17] DEBUG a.p.q.j.l.LiveEventsByPersistenceIdPublisher - replay completed for persistenceId [rooms], currSeqNo [4]
14:11:34.376 [rooms-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] DEBUG a.p.q.j.l.LiveEventsByPersistenceIdPublisher - request replay for persistenceId [rooms] from [4] to [9223372036854775807] limit [100]
14:11:34.378 [rooms-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] DEBUG a.p.q.j.l.LiveEventsByPersistenceIdPublisher - replay completed for persistenceId [rooms], currSeqNo [4]
```

Here is the program I wrote trying to achieve it.

```
implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()(context)
val queries = PersistenceQuery(context.system).readJournalFor[LeveldbReadJournal](
      LeveldbReadJournal.Identifier)
val src: Source[EventEnvelope, NotUsed] = queries.eventsByPersistenceId("rooms", 0L, Long.MaxValue)
val events: Source[Any, NotUsed] = src.map(_.event)
val future = events.runWith(Sink.foreach{
  case x: RoomCreated => process(x)
  case x: RoomDeleted => process(x)
  case x => logger.error(s"Could not spawn $x")
})
```

Comment: Where is the code that is producing that log statement?  I think you need to show a little more code so that we can understand why it is that the query seems to be executed multiple times.

Comment: Pre start of once instatiated actor

Comment: Are you starting multiple instances of this actor, or is it being re-started by a supervisor in response to an exception that's happening somewhere in the handling?

Comment: I would have noticed whether he crashed, because when he starts he does a bunch of work spamming the console out with "Spawned Child" so he is not restarting. When i'll be back tomorrow at work i'll post more code.

Comment: @cmbaxter What if the foreach is the problem? What if it want's to check whether any new events happened?

Comment: It does. It's a live event stream. If you don't want a live stream then use `currentEventsByPersistenceId` instead.

Comment: @cmbaxter Thank you kind sir! It's working as I intended in the first place. Post it as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the difference in your expected behavior and what you were actually seeing is that `eventsByPersistenceId` is a "live" stream.  That means that not only will it return events starting within the offset range you supplied (you are starting at 0 and going to Long.MaxValue, so everything), but if will keep sending you new events as they come in.  If you don't want a live stream, then change the call to `currentEventsByPersistenceId` instead.  This will only include things up to that point in time (the time you are making the request) and not be a live stream.  That should be what you are looking for.